# Detect cellular antenna structures

Tags: gprs, lte

I am monitoring cellular antennas for my work. Using a SIM800L chip (2g) and a SIM71200A (3g and 4g), and with different AT commands,  I get a list of the nearby antennas and the transmit power. With these data, I can position them in a certain area and then photograph them.

Among the data I get are :

```
 -mcc: mobile country code
 -mnc: mobile network code  (cell company code)
 -lac: location area code  
 -bsic: basestation identification code  
 -cellid: Id of the cell
```

**What I do not understand is that a set of data makes a cell unique.**

Option 1:  MCC+MNC+LAC+CELID

Option 2:  MCC+MNC+LAC+BSIC

Option 3:  MCC+MNC+BSIC

I did not find information on the web that explains if an antenna (the large structure) contains more than one cell (CELID) of the same company ... or if there is one or more BSIC (Base station id) of the same company in the same physical antenna.

Important: I try to determine how to find the antennas (the whole structure), I do not care if you have one or more cells in the same place

PD: AT commands are: AT+CENg, AT+CRUS and AT+CMGRMI=4 (for 2g, 3g and 4g each one)

Answer (score 0):

A cell id is unique within the LAC (or TAC if LTE, but logically the same idea) for any carrier (identified with MCC+MNC). A base station can possibly handle multiple cells. A common configuration is to have a base station handle 3 cells in 120 degree sectors.

There is nothing stopping a carrier from deploying multiple cells onto a single antenna. How common or uncommon is probably country and carrier dependent. Depending on the bands a carrier is licensed to use in a particular country, it might be easy to design an single antenna to cover these bands; or it might be really hard. It might make sense depending on the physical situation (i.e. municipal regulations on antennas on roofs/poles/etc) to have less antennas and hence force cells to share antennas. Long story short, implementation is left to the discretion of the carrier.

Comment: So, you say that the base id (BSIC) is unique for a physical antenna? or can be multiple BSIC to the same atenna?